# Regex match array notation

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find array-like occurrences in a string.

For instance for this text

Ut ac nisi eget est tempus mattis. Sed et dapibus lorem. Suspendisse laoreet ante arcu, sed ornare **a(diam)[test]** ornare eget. Nunc **a(pulvinar)[anoter][test]** porttitor accumsan. Donec quis accumsan enim.Ut sed sem posuere, **a(pharetra)[another[nested][a(test)]]** sapien a, molestie odio. Donec euismod, lectus et sollicitudin condimentum, felis dolor feugiat arcu

i want to match bold parts.

i got this far:

```
\a\((.*?)\)(\[.*?])+
```

this matches first two, but the last test has the last closing bracket missing.(If i nest once more 2 closing brackets becomes missing)

results:

```
a(diam)[test]
a(pulvinar)[anoter][test]
a(pharetra)[another[nested][a(test)] <--- last closing bracket missing.
```

any help?

Comment: You might know about this already, but:
http://www.cyber-reality.com/regexy.html Has been a great help for me when building regexes

Comment: You can't do that with regex (at least, JS flavor).

Comment: ended up with \a((.*?))((?:[.*?]+)+).

Comment: @thg435: it's posibble to match but i guess it's not possible to capture every [] seperately when they are nested.

Comment: @Jon, thanks. i am using http://regexpal.com/ but it's always useful to have a cheat sheet like that handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about embedding the nested structure in regular expression like this:

```
a\(\w+\)(\[.+?(\[.+\])*\])+
              ---------  
              embeded nesting
```

### EDIT:

```
(a\(\w+\)(?:\[.+?(?:\[.+\])*\])+)
```

Added non-capturing symbols to mitigate "undefined" captures.

Comment: Thanks! Everyting is fine, but of course it captures "undefined" when there is no nesting. I am guessing capturing everything between every [] seperately is not possible with js regex.  i ended up with \a\((.*?)\)((?:\[.*?]+)+). only added + after last ] in my original regex and changed capturing groups. Capturing this way is mot logical for my use case.

Comment: I edited my answer. Now there is only one group for capturing whole text.

Comment: Used slightly modified version of your edited expression in the end. My version was not properly matching if there was nothing between [].